# parallel processing and Job API

Tags: python, add-on, data-blocks

Someone told me that the long data processing task can be parallel processing by JOB API of Blender. But I can't find any doc or example about JOB API. Could someone give me some suggestion about it?

Comment: Just wondering, why ask here instead of asking that "someone"?

Comment: He is so kindly. He told me more about Blender. But he is busy now, and can't be our consultant. So I want to know more about Blender. I found that the Blender have command option -b. I think that the Job API is C API. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job API is a C API, and not exposed to Python. For parallel processing of data in Python, use the regular tools Python gives you for this, like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have read some articles about Blender UI development and proposal. I found that the UI development on Blender is huge job. Would you can tell me which files are concerned in UI?

Comment: This is not a forum. If you're interested in Blender development, visit https://wiki.blender.org/