# How to copy "stop this job" behavior with API?

Tags: python, rendering

In a nutshell:

[image: stop render job with Python]

I want to do whatever clicking that "X" button does, except with the Python API (cancel a render in progress).

Hovering the mouse over the button doesn't give a Python tooltip like other buttons do.

Right-clicking the button and then clicking "Edit Source" shows me the location of the source file, which contains:

```py
# C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_statusbar.py
...
class STATUSBAR_HT_header(Header):
    ...
    def draw(self, context):
        ...
        # Progress Bar
        layout.template_running_jobs()
```

So it seems that `layout.template_running_jobs()` is what shows the "X" button. The documentation for [template_running_jobs()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_running_jobs) doesn't give any useful information.

[This solution to a different question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106506/125777) mentions something called the "job API", which I'm not familiar with but I suspect that it is related with the problem that I am having.

**Is there any way to copy this behavior with the Python API?**

**System info**:

- Windows 10
- [image: Blender 2.93.0]

Comment: maybe not a solution - but a workaround. I assume you are the one who starts the render by python. So instead of render "everything" you could just render e.g. 10 frames...and if noting "special" (like a button pressed) happened, render next 10 frames...and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Actually, what that button does is stop the rendering mid-frame. I was making a script that starts rendering when my PC goes idle, and then stops rendering when it detects mouse/keyboard activity. The best I could do was stop after the current frame is rendered, but I wanted to stop the rendering immediately. I made my own work-around by spawning a new process for rendering using the Python `multiprocessing` library, and then terminating the process when mouse/keyboard activity is detected. I'm using Blender as a Python module (I don't know if it works with vanilla Blender).